# audio on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How can I do the following things with iPhone sdk:
1. Access built in microphone, get amplitude of a sound.
2. Record sound from microphone into a file.
3. Playback the audio recorded from the microphone.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Have look on this page : http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/tutorial/how-to-play-audio-with-the-iphone-sdk